# R Regression from two tables

Tags: r, regression

I have these two tables of `GDP` and `Employment` for example:

```
Country GDP    2000   2001   2002   2003
Afghanistan    3     4       5      6
Belarus        5     6       7      8
Belgium        7     8       9      10

Country Employment     2000   2001   2002   2003
Afghanistan            3     4      5       6
Belarus                10    11     12      15
Belgium                7     10     11      13
```

How do I run a regression model between `GDP` and `Employment`, for each country between the years?

Comment: What is the statistical form of the regression you wish to run (clearly specify the response and the covariates). The "standard" function for linear regression at least is `lm()`. Have you made any attempt to use this function? What specific problems are you encountering? If you wanted something other than a linear model, what model did you want? As written, this really isn't a programming question. If you need statistical advice, try [stats.se] instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you seem new-ish to R, and programming and statistics in general here's a simple way to get your data into a more usable format for a simple linear model using the `lm(...)` function. A few notes about what's going in here: You cannot have column names that are numeric, it's easier/preferable to work with simple modeling with distinct columns, hence the reshaping.

```
gdp <- data.frame(country = c('Afghanistan', 'Belarus', 'Belgium'),
                  x2000 = c(3, 5, 7),
                  x2001 = c(4, 6, 8),
                  x2002 = c(5, 7, 9),
                  x2003 = c(6, 8, 10)
                  )

emp <- data.frame(country = c('Afghanistan', 'Belarus', 'Belgium'),
                  x2000 = c(3, 10, 7),
                  x2001 = c(4, 11, 10),
                  x2002 = c(5, 12, 11),
                  x2003 = c(6, 15, 13)
                  )

require(reshape)

gdp.long <- reshape(gdp,
                    varying = c('x2000', 'x2001', 'x2002', 'x2003'),
                    v.names = 'gdp',
                    timevar = 'year',
                    times = c('x2000', 'x2001', 'x2002', 'x2003'),
                    direction = 'long'
                    )


emp.long <- reshape(emp,
                    varying = c('x2000', 'x2001', 'x2002', 'x2003'),
                    v.names = 'emp',
                    timevar = 'year',
                    times = c('x2000', 'x2001', 'x2002', 'x2003'),
                    direction = 'long'
                    )

df <- merge(gdp.long, emp.long, by = c('country', 'year'))

df$year <- as.numeric(gsub('x', '', df$year))

model <- lm(gdp~emp, data = df)
```

Now your linear model looks like this:

```
> summary(model)

Call:
lm(formula = gdp ~ emp, data = df)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.9612 -1.0084 -0.1199  1.1081  1.7618 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)   2.7043     1.0150   2.664  0.02372 * 
emp           0.4257     0.1053   4.043  0.00235 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.336 on 10 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6204,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5825 
F-statistic: 16.34 on 1 and 10 DF,  p-value: 0.00235
```

Comment: The problem is that I have data 223 Countries in total and 26 Years in the format in my original Question. Is there a way to quickly get a regression model for each country between GDP and Employment for all the Years. In the answer above I see there is one Coefficient for all the countries.

Comment: @NickZizos you just need to use a for loop or some other method to subset your data frame. I don't understand what you mean by 'for all the years'.